# How to return no body / content for errors / error_page in nginx?

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-403

If a file is not found, or forbidden, etc. -- I'd really like to just return the HTTP status code and no body content.
Something like:

```
error_page 403 404 body="";
```

What are the current (2015) best practices?

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure if this is the best practise but it still works even without creating actual empty file.

```
error_page 403 404 /__empty-error-page__.html;

location = /__empty-error-page__.html {
  internal;
  return 200 "";
}
```

Comment: if this endpoint is potentially meant to be rendered by browsers I suggest adding `default_type text/html;` in the `location`, otherwise browsers (at least Chromium) throw `err_invalid_response`, misleading the user to think there was some error serving the request

Answer (score 0):

The best I've come up with is to create a zero-byte file:

`$ touch _.json`

set that location to be internal in my nginx config, and point the error_page to it:

`location /_.json {
  internal;
}
error_page 403 404 /_.json;`

Depending on your content-type, replace `_.json` with your desired `_.mime-type-extension`.

Answer (score -1):

Realistically, all current options imply location per error code wich isn't a clean solution. When you compile your nginx, simply deal with bodies in `src/http/ngx_http_special_response.c`